# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._dist_metrics'

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I trained a Kernel Density model, then dumped the model using joblib. I then made a function while calling the same .pkl file. It works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it on a cloud machine and create a docker image out of the same I get one of the following errors:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._dist_metrics'
```

or

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._kde'
```

What might be causing this issue and how to solve it?

The Code for the initial training is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
%matplotlib inline 
import seaborn as sns
import csv 
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import joblib


arr = df_trim.values
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.2).fit(arr)
joblib.dump(kde, 'kde.pkl')

 # This is the array that is used for training 
 # array([[3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5],
       [4. , 4. , 3.5, 4. ],
       [3.5, 3. , 2.5, 3. ],
       ...,
       [2.5, 2.5, 2. , 2. ],
       [1.5, 1.5, 2. , 2.5],
       [3. , 3. , 2.5, 3. ]])
```

The following code is for the function that invokes this saved model:

```
from itertools import combinations
import joblib


filename = 'kde.pkl'  # filename for the model's pickle file.
model = joblib.load(filename) # loading the pre trained model using joblib.



def rSubset(arr, r):
  
    # return list of all subsets of length r
    # to deal with duplicate subsets use 
    # set(list(combinations(arr, r)))

    return list(combinations(arr, r))



def datapred(*args):
    
    no_args = len(args)
    args = list(args)
        
    pred_data = []
    model_score = []
    arr = [3.5 , 4 ,  3,  2.5,  1.5,  2,   1,   0.5,  0.25]
    n = (4 - no_args)
    comb_arr = (rSubset(arr, n))

    if(no_args==1):

        gpa1 = args[0]

        for i in range(1,len(comb_arr)):
                                      
            var = comb_arr[i]
            var = list(var)
            var = [gpa1]+var
            output = model.score_samples([var])
            model_score.append(output)
            pred_data.append(var)
            position = model_score.index(max(model_score))
            result = pred_data[position]
            return(result)

    elif(no_args==2):

        gpa1 = args[0]
        gpa2 = args[1] 

        for i in range(1,len(comb_arr)):
                                      
            var = comb_arr[i]
            var = list(var)
            var = [gpa1]+[gpa2]+var

            output = model.score_samples([var])
            model_score.append(output)
            pred_data.append(var)
            position = model_score.index(max(model_score))
            result = pred_data[position]
            return(result)

    elif(no_args==3):

        gpa1 = args[0]
        gpa2 = args[1]
        gpa3 = args[2] 

        for i in range(1,len(comb_arr)):
                                      
            var = comb_arr[i]
            var = list(var)
            var = [gpa1]+[gpa2]+[gpa3]+var

            output = model.score_samples([var])
            model_score.append(output)
            pred_data.append(var)
            position = model_score.index(max(model_score))
            result = pred_data[position]
            return(result)
```

Also the following is the requirements.txt file for the docker image :

```
logger
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
joblib==0.15.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pandas==1.0.3
scikit-learn==0.19
sklearn >= 0.0
threadpoolctl==2.0.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
xgboost ==1.5.2
scipy >= 0.0
```

Comment: Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre]; do not just post all of your code here as-is, remove any code that may come *after* the error, since it is never executed, hence irrelevant to the issue (your errors seem to come already from the imports, hence all the rest of the code may be irrelevant).

Comment: @desertnaut all of this is executed before the error. This is the piece of code that works fine on my local machine and when i try to build a docker image out of the same, with the requirements.txt ( as i mentioned in the question) that is when i get the error.

Comment: Again, where *exactly* in the code does the error pop up? Please post the *full* error trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scikit-learn` library is a different version on your cloud machine.

Specifically, the `sklearn.neighbors._dist_metrics` was removed around version `1.0.2`. Perhaps your docker container is not actually using your requirements.txt properly.

Here's an example of different versions:

This one doesn't throw an error

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.24.2'
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import _dist_metrics
```

This one throws an error

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'1.0.2'
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import _dist_metrics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name '_dist_metrics' from 'sklearn.neighbors'
```

Comment: Thanks @A_toaster, the scikit-learn version on my environment was 1.0.2 and reverting it to 0.24.2 and then training the model fixed the issue! (p.s : the original requirement.txt had scikit-learn at 1.0.2 as well, but i had changed it during debugging)